# How to handle response in AWS API Gateway iOS

Tags: ios, swift, api, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have generated `API Gateway SDK` for `ios` for my API. In `SDK` I have two types of file one which make request and other is to handle response-

1) TESTGetAllDataClient

2) TESTEmpty

```
let serviceClient = TESTGetAllDataClient.defaultClient()
serviceClient.rootPost("2015").continueWithBlock{ (task:AWSTask!) -> (AnyObject!) in
        if task.error != nil {

            print(task.error)

        } else {

let resultDict :TESTEmpty = task.result as! TESTEmpty

        }
        return nil
    }
```

Here `TestEmpty` is the type of `response`. But in my `TestEmpty` class that i have got from `API Gateway SDK`,does not contain any method to extract dictionary form object. `TestEmpty` `implementation class` is below:

```
@implementation TESTEmpty

+ (NSDictionary *)JSONKeyPathsByPropertyKey {
    return @{

            };
}

@end
```

Do I need to write my own methods to handle the response or it will be provided by `SDK`? Please respond if you know anything about it. I am new to `AWS API Gateway`.

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The iOS SDK generates the classes based on the models defined in your API. There is a default model called "Empty" which is represented by your "TestEmpty" class. Since this model doesn't define any properties / attributes, you won't be able to get data out of it.

In order to use the generated SDKs in a meaningful way, you'd need to define the expected output of your APIs with models (see [Use Models and Mapping Templates for Payload Mappings](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-models.html)). After you defined these models, make sure that you use them as "Response Models" in your methods' "Method Execution" page.

When you followed the steps above and re-deployed your API, your generated SDKs should contain the model classes you attached to your methods. You can then use those in the SDK to extract the data from the HTTP response.

Hope this helps,

Jurgen, API Gateway

Comment: -Thanks a lot for your response.Will try as you suggested.

Comment: Jurgen, is it required to set up models? If my backend returns json and I want the response body to just flow all the way to the client, is it alright to not create any models? We are debugging an issue with our generated SDK right now and I want to ensure that it's not related to our lack of models. Thanks! :)